# Print from Midlet in Windows Mobile with JavaFx

Tags: java-me, printing, windows-mobile, javafx

I have a `Midlet` that runs over `JavaFx` on Windows Mobile.  Everything works fine.  The problem is that the Bluetooth api is not available and the printer works with bluetooth.
I can print from outside the midlet in the phone with the "Wireless printer" option.
Is ther a way to print using this option from the midlet ?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple as HttpConnection & writing DataOutputStream, First of all you need to make Serial Connection with that IP address. After making Connection you need to make DataOutputStream for writing files/words , these will goes to printer & will print it. I did same for Bluetooth Printer previously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was doing something similiar to what you said but I put in the open method this:   Connector.open("comm:com2;baudrate=9600");  and that throws a connection not found exception.  So, what should I put on that method?

Comment: when you are connecting using Bluetooth you need to pass its UUID for connection.